# linear function that satisfies both conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

I am having problems understanding how to solve this question.

Find a linear function that satisfies both of the given conditions.

$f(-1) = 5, f(1) = 6$

Thanks, 
*Note: i have the answer, just need help understanding*

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** What is the general form of a linear function?

($f(x) =$ something something $x$ something something...)

Answer (score 0):

A linear function (in one variable) is of the form $f(x) = ax + b$, where $a$ and $b$ are constants. The two conditions $f(-1) = 5$ and $f(1) = 6$ determine the value of $a$ and $b$.

To be explicit, using these two conditions, we have 
$$ -a+b = 5,$$
$$ a+b = 6.$$
Now solve the equations above to get $a$ and $b$.